# Authentication with webbrowser.open() in Python

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, python-webbrowser

I want to parse a page and download all the videos it contains.
Since the page required authentication, I created a session

```
my_session = requests.Session()             
login = my_session.post(signin_link,data=signin,headers=post_head)

return my_session
......
......

page = my_session.get("page_url")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
```

Now, I have all the download links but when I try to open them, using

`webbrowser.open(url)`,

I am redirected to the sign-in page. Is there any way to authenticate with the webbrowser.open() or to to download those links using the session object?

Thanks